# Result from promise React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication

Here is me connexion method:

```
export  function connexionUser(email, password) {

    result = firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log("res: ", res)
            return true;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            return false;
        });
        return result;
};
```

Here my method in index.js:

```
login = () => {

    const { email, password } = this.state;
    var result = connexionUser(email, password);
    console.log("result");
    console.log(result);
    if (result == true) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Favorites');
    }
}
```

Problem : 
I would like to get the result of "connexionUser()"  in my index.js to be able to manage the navigation or something else.
But my result isn't true or false:

```
result
A {
  "a": 0,
  "b": null,
  "c": A {
    "a": 0,
    "b": qb {
      "a": [Circular],
      "b": [Function anonymous],
      "c": false,
      "f": null,
      "g": [Function anonymous],
      "next": null,
    },
    "c": A {
      "a": 0,
      "b": qb {
        .....
        .....and more
```

PS : i am a beginner in React native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always try to throw in a `console.log` to see what the output of the result is. If you're having trouble debugging with React Native, [the docs on debugging](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging) are really helpful.

As it stands, your registerUser will return `undefined` since you aren't actually returning the result. I imagine you're trying to return `result` in your `then` statement, but the `then` statement should be receiving the results of your firebase function and returning those results. I'd recommend reading up a bit about [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) for clarification on how they work. One way you could rewrite this would be:

```
export function registerUser(email, password) {

    result = firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((res) => {
            console.log("res: ", res)
            return res;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            alert(errorMessage);
        });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It seems like your new goal is to achieve two things:

1. You'd like for your conditional `if` statement to trigger
2. You'd like to pass your `results` object to the child component

If that is the case, then you could always simplify your conditional to simply be: `if (result)` since an object will always be true (https://medium.com/@ariel.salem1989/alternative-truth-truthy-vs-true-4d318e78f45).

To pass down the results to the following component, simply follow the docs:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html